# How does this allocator play the role of debugging?

Tags: c++, stl, allocator, sgi

When I read the source code of SGI/STL, I notice that

```
template <class _Alloc>
class debug_alloc {

private:

  enum {_S_extra = 8};  // Size of space used to store size.  Note
                        // that this must be large enough to preserve
                        // alignment.

public:

  static void* allocate(size_t __n)
  {
    char* __result = (char*)_Alloc::allocate(__n + (int) _S_extra);
    *(size_t*)__result = __n;
    return __result + (int) _S_extra;
  }

  static void deallocate(void* __p, size_t __n)
  {
    char* __real_p = (char*)__p - (int) _S_extra;
    assert(*(size_t*)__real_p == __n);
    _Alloc::deallocate(__real_p, __n + (int) _S_extra);
  }

  static void* reallocate(void* __p, size_t __old_sz, size_t __new_sz)
  {
    char* __real_p = (char*)__p - (int) _S_extra;
    assert(*(size_t*)__real_p == __old_sz);
    char* __result = (char*)
      _Alloc::reallocate(__real_p, __old_sz + (int) _S_extra,
                                   __new_sz + (int) _S_extra);
    *(size_t*)__result = __new_sz;
    return __result + (int) _S_extra;
  }

};
```

which is a debug template.

I can see that it assure that the allocated space is always larger than 8bytes, and I can also see that it replace the contents starting from the address of __result by using `*(size_t*)__result = __n;` but I am really confused about the purpose of this.

Why allocate the space then replace the contents with __n?
Why then return `__result + (int) _S_extra;` and define `char* __real_p = (char*)__p - (int) _S_extra;`?
Please explain in detail how function `void* allocate(size_t __n)` and `void deallocate(void* __p, size_t __n)` work on memory.

Link to source code: https://github.com/karottc/sgi-stl/blob/master/concept_checks.h

Comment: The purpose is described in the comment about `_S_extra`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I can read english very well. The reason I asked this question seems obvious that I don't get how it handle alignment.

Comment: It seems to just track the allocation size and ensures that the deallocation is the same size, i don't think it does anything more than that

Comment: You didn't ask about alignment. You asked about the purpose, which is to store the size of the allocation so it can be verified. Answering how it works is dificult without knowing what exactly you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allocator uses an 8-byte header in front of every allocation to record its size.  It is common to store metadata like this next to the actual allocation. Even though the header contains a 4-byte int, 8 bytes ensure that the returned pointer is aligned to 8 bytes, a common requirement for larger types..

As you can read from the code, allocate asks for n+8 bytes (call the resulting allocation p) , stores the size at the the beginning and returns p+8.

Deallocate and reallocate are given the pointer p+8,so have to first subtract to get back to the real allocation.